# Audio track looping in Javascript without a delay

Tags: javascript, html, audio, buzz.js, soundjs

I'm currently helping a friend develop a web application in which I need ~6 audio tracks (all using the same time signature) to continuously loop and stay in sync. To give context, it is a typeface-music pairing application where as soon as a typeface is chosen, the associated audio loop starts playing and as the user keeps picking typefaces, the tracks layer and begin to resemble a song.

I've tried using SoundJS and the Buzz sound library, but I keep running into the same problem: there is always a slight delay between loops. This would be fine if all my audio tracks were the same length, but they aren't, so very quickly things go out of sync.

This seems to be a known problem, but I can't seem to find any answer to how to fix it. I came across Hivenfour's [SeamlessLoop 2.0](https://github.com/Hivenfour/SeamlessLoop), but - unless I'm using it completely wrong - it doesn't actually seem to work (setting a volume returns an error).

If anyone has experience with this, I would truly appreciate any input! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm on my phone so I'm not going to find it but I ran into a similar problem and found the answer on SO. The trick is to have TWO audio instances per audio file and use call backs to start the other instance when the current instance finishes. There is currently no way of seamlessly looping that works cross browser but the two instance trick is a good work around.

Comment: just curious, I've been trying to get SeamLessLoop 2.0 to work, but in their example they use some library called BASE64UTF8 that i can't find...how did u get an example up and running?

Answer (score 0):

SoundJS WebAudioPlugin uses a look ahead approach with web audio that will loop seamlessly, which is described [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/) in a what will probably be a very helpful on audio timing.
Also be aware that some compression formats will insert white noise into sounds.  I believe mp3 does this.  WAV is supported broadly and does not.

As for HTMLAudioPlugin, we loop as smoothly as the browser will allow but it does not have the same precision as WebAudio.

Hope that helps.